# Trying to get a mouseover on an overlay with jquery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I have things almost where I want them. When I started working with jquery tools, I didn't realize that the project was dead and that the forums seem permanently down. However, I ALMOST have what I need.

All I need at this point is to get the mouseover working for areas on an imagemap. I have the click working. The work in progress is at http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/contact-us/360-joomla-content

I have an image with an image map

```
<img name="circle" src="images/mt-auburn-360.jpg" alt="mt-auburn-360" usemap="#mt-auburn-360-map" />
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

There is some css styling

I am preloading the images but I'm not sure that is necessary.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     Image0 = new Image(800, 659)
                                 Image0.src = "http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360.jpg"
                              Image1 = new Image(800, 659)
                                 Image1.src = "http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360-slice-1.jpg"
                              Image2 = new Image(800, 659)
                                 Image2.src = "http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-
```

(clipped out the repetitive code
    // ]]>

I have functions that were handling the overlay of the slices in my old version. I don't think this is necessary with jquery tools

> //
>
> ```
>                           }
> function slice4() {
>                                          document.circle.src = Image4.src;
> ```

This code seems to be what makes the jquery tools actually work. I added the area, onhover and onmouseover to try to get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img[rel]").overlay();
$("area[rel]").overlay();
$("onhover[rel]").overlay();
$("onmouseover[rel]").overlay();
});
```

There is code which does the styling of the overlay

```
<style>

 /* the overlayed element */
.simple_overlay {

    /* must be initially hidden */
    display:none;

    /* place overlay on top of other elements */
    z-index:10000;

    /* styling */
    background-color:#333;

    width:675px;
    min-height:200px;
    border:1px solid #666;

    /* CSS3 styling for latest browsers */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 90px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 90px #000;
}

/* close button positioned on upper right corner */
.simple_overlay .close {
    background-image:url(/media/img/overlay/close.png);
    position:absolute;
    right:-15px;
    top:-15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
}
```

Here is the code that links the image for the overlay of one of the slices

```
<div name="slice1ovr" class="simple_overlay" id="slice2">
  <!-- large image -->
  <img src="images/mt-auburn-360-slice-2.jpg" />

  <!-- image details -->
  <div class="details">
    <h3>The Barcelona Pavilion</h3>
    <h4>Barcelona, Spain</h4>
    <p>The content ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then I have my image map, part of it is here

```
<area shape="poly" coords="397,278,476,140,530,182,565,238,577,284,580,318,421,319,415,293" alt="National Training Team" href="http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360-slice-1.jpg" onmouseover="slice1()" onmouseout="original()">
<area shape="poly" coords="399,359,483,492,530,456,561,405,575,363,581,319,421,319,417,341"  alt="National Performance Team" href="http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360-slice-2.jpg" rel="#slice2" $("#slice2").overlay({event:'mouseover'});" onmouseout="original()" >
<area shape="poly" coords="350,361,278,503,324,519,364,526,425,520,485,495,398,359,376,366" alt="National Retention Team" href="http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360-slice-3.jpg" onmouseover="slice3()" onmouseout="original()">
<area shape="poly" coords="328,317,169,317,175,382,200,430,242,479,277,501,351,359,332,340" alt="National Purchasing Team" href="http://mtauburn.netcontrolinc.com/joomla/images/mt-auburn-360-slice-4.jpg" onmouseover="slice4()" onmouseout="original()">
```

If you mouse over any of the slices, the images swap with my original document.circle code in the functions. However, I could not get any transitions to work with that. So, I tried jquery tools. If you click on the slice that is around the 3 o'clock position, an overlay shows that has the css formatting.

All I need to do to finish this is to figure out how to make the overlay appear on a mouseover instead of a click.

I'd really appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
$('.hover-element').mouseover(function(){   
    $('overlay-selector').overlay({  
        load:true  //this makes the overlay load when function is called instead of on click
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

The default overlay loads on a click, so see the section titled 'Opening overlays programmatically' here:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/trigger.html